# How to revert a range of commits when it contains some merge commits?

Tags: git

I am trying to revert a range of commits where some commits are merge commits. I need the branch in exact copy before these range of "bad" commits (for example, last good commit is "A")

`git revert B1^..B10`

If some are merge commits, it will return error something like "...not allowed due to a merge but no -m option was given".

If I provide the option `-m 1`, it will revert but I am not getting the correct revision of code exactly the same if I checkout commit ID "A".

Note, I do want to keep history so using the `reset` command is not an option.

Comment: This looks relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47811491/git-revert-range-of-commits-already-pushed-with-merge-commits-in-between

Answer (score 2):

> I need the branch in exact copy before these range of "bad" commits (for example, last good commit is "A")

```
git read-tree -um A
git commit
```

Comment: This looks like a winner. Thanks for the tip on `read-tree`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to undo the last commit totally from git history, as well as the changes file changes, if you have NOT pushed:

git reset HEAD~1

If you have pushed

git reset HEAD

Comment: I did consider that but I want to keep history.

Comment: I think you should be able to use git reset --soft HEAD~1 to keep the history